# Add shipping Rate to cart considering both weight and price of the cart

Tags: php, woocommerce

Want to add shipping charge using code in woo commerce. here is my requirements.

> If maximum weight of the order is 500 grams and: if order value is <=
>   $89.99 , then shipping charge is $30.00 if order value is $90.00 >
>   $178.99,then shipping charge is $32.50 if order value is $179.00 > $
>   269.99,then shipping charge is $35.00 if order value is $270.00 > $359.99,then shipping charge is $37.50 if order value is $360.00 >
>   $650.00,then shipping charge is $40.00
>
> If maximum weight of the order is more than or equals to 500 grams
>   and: if order value is more than $650.00,then shipping charge is $70

So, how can I add custom shipping charge as per my above requirements I tried below code

But it cause the website blank.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'calculate_shipping');



function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
        global $woocommerce;

            if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight > 500) {
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 89){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 90 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 178 ){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 179 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 269){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 270 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 359){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 360 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 650){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }

            }else{
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 650){
                    $cost = 70; 
                }
          }

    $rate = array(
        'id' => $this->id,
        'label' => $this->title,
        'cost' => $cost,
        'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
    );

    $this->add_rate( $rate );
    }
```

Comment: do you have error reporting on en do you display errors? what does it say?

Comment: It showing the error Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ...

Comment: I think you have to post the complete php document

Comment: This is the exact code I placed in my function.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it:

By adding a new custom Flat rate Rate and hiding the default flat rate.

Here is the function I add in my function.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate', 'add_another_custom_flat_rate', 10, 2 );

function add_another_custom_flat_rate( $method, $rate ) {
    $new_rate          = $rate;
    $new_rate['id']    .= ':' . 'custom_rate_name';
    $new_rate['label'] = 'Shipping and handling'; 

global $woocommerce;
//echo 'weight'.$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
//echo 'price'.$woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
            if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight <= 500) {
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 89){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 90 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 178 ){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 179 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 269){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 270 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 359){
                    $cost = 30; 
                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 360 && $woocommerce->cart->subtotal <= 650){
                    $cost = 30; 

                }
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 650){
                    $cost = 70; 
                }

            }else{
                if($woocommerce->cart->subtotal >= 650){
                    $cost = 70; 
                }
          }
    $new_rate['cost']  = $cost; // Add $2 to the cost
    $method->add_rate( $new_rate );
}
```